# PHP mailer connection error

Tags: php

I am getting following error:
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) 
The following From address failed: test@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected

What is problem in my code or any other problem?

My openssl is also enable

I am doing following coding:

```
<?php
      include("securimage/securimage.php");
      $img = new Securimage();
      $valid = $img->check($_POST['code']);

      if($valid == true) {

        require_once('class.phpmailer.php'); 

        $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
        $body="Name : ".$_POST['name']."<br>";
        $body .="Subject : ".$_POST['subject']."<br>";
        $body .="Phone : ".$_POST['phone']."<br>";
        $body .="Email : ".$_POST['email']."<br>";
        $body .=$_POST['comment']."<br>";
        $mail->IsSMTP(); 
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                 
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
        $mail->Host= "smtp.gmail.com";     
        $mail->Port       = 465;                   
        $mail->Username   = "contactus@gmail.com";  
        $mail->Password   = "contactus"; 
        $mail->From        = $_POST['email'];          
        $mail->FromName    = $_POST['name'];

        $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email']);
        $mail->Subject    = "Contact Us";
        $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; 
        $mail->MsgHTML($body);
        $mail->AddAddress('niyati@ngplweb.com', 'Niyati'); 

        if(!$mail->Send()) 
        {
              setcookie("msg","Error.",time()+5);
              header("location:contactus.php");
        } 
        else 
        {
               setcookie("msg","Thank you.We will get back to you soon......",time()+5);
               header("location:contactus.php");
         }
       } 
       else 
       {
               setcookie("msg","Incorrect Captcha.",time()+5);
               header("location:contactus.php");
        } 
        ?>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant segment of the PHP error log

Comment: @sanki: See the `require_once`. -- `require_once('class.phpmailer.php');`

Comment: @AmalMurali: that was so unobservant of me :(

Answer (score 2):

Your password assignment is incorrect. This is probably the reason why your connection doesn't work.

```
 mail->Password = "contactus"; 
^---
```

should be changed to:

```
$mail->Password = "contactus";
```

Comment: @user2870941: I just tested it and it works fine for me. Are you sure your `class.phpmailer.php` file is the latest one? Download it from [here](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/phpmailer/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/Previous%20Versions/PHPMailer%20v5.1/PHPMailer_v5.1.zip?r=&ts=1384426816&use_mirror=garr). Also, set `SMTPDebug` to `2` and see if that outputs any errors.

Answer (score 1):

"SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) The following From address failed: test@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected"

This is because

```
    $mail->Username   = "contactus@gmail.com";  
    $mail->Password   = "contactus";
```

are not valid ones. try using some valid username and password and i think all will be well.
By valid i meant real username and password of real "gmail id".